# GUI Python: The first window it has an extract data button and a show data button. I don't get why the window is closing when pushing show data button

Tags: pyqt, pyautogui, qt-signals

import json

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QThread
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

// TazzExtractor.py

```py
import requests
from unidecode import unidecode


class TazzExtractor(QThread):
    data = pyqtSignal(object)
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def extractData(self):
        # Extract all cities from TAZZ
        url = "https://tazz.ro"

        # make a request to the site
        response = requests.get(url)

        # pull data out of HTML file
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

        cities = []

        # add every city to cities array
        for city in soup.select('div.cities-cards-list a'):
            cities.append(city.text.strip())

        # Extract restaurants info for each city
        data = {}
        for city in cities:
            # remove the discritics in the city name
            city = unidecode(city)

            # make the city name lowercase to match the https request
            city = city.lower()

            url = f"https://tazz.ro/{city}/restaurante"
            response = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
            restaurants = []

            for i, restaurant in soup.select('div.partnersListLayout div.store-card'):
                name = restaurant.select_one('div.store-info h3')
                if name is not None:
                    name = name.text.strip()
                else:
                    name = ''
                stars = restaurant.select_one('div.store-info div.store-rating')
                if stars is not None:
                    stars = stars.text.strip()
                else:
                    stars = ''

                description = restaurant.select_one('div.store-delivery')
                if description is not None:
                    description = description.text.strip()
                else:
                    description = ''

                restaurants.append({"name": name, "stars": stars, "description": description})

            progressPercent = int((i+1) / len(cities) * 100)
            self.progress.emit(progressPercent)
            data[city] = restaurants

        self.data.emit(data)
```

// MainView.py

```py
from helpers.TazzExtractor import TazzExtractor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QTableWidgetItem, QTableWidget, QProgressBar


# display the extracted data in a table
class RestaurantTable(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Tazz Restaurants"
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, self.width, self.height)

        self.table_widget = QTableWidget()

        # set the number of rows to the length of data
        row_count = sum(len(restaurants) for city, restaurants in data.items())
        self.table_widget.setRowCount(row_count)

        # set column count to 3 (name, description, stars)
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Restaurant', 'Description', 'Stars'])

        row = 0
        print(data)
        for city, restaurants in data.items():
            for restaurant in restaurants:
                self.table_widget.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(restaurant["name"]))
                self.table_widget.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(restaurant["description"]))
                self.table_widget.setItem(row, 2, QTableWidgetItem(restaurant["stars"]))
                row += 1

            self.table_widget.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(''))
            self.table_widget.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(''))


class MainView(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.data = None
        self.title = "Tazz Cities"
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, self.width, self.height)

        self.extractor = TazzExtractor()

        self.progressBar = QProgressBar()
        self.progressBar.setMinimum(0)
        self.progressBar.setMaximum(100)

        self.extractButton = QPushButton("Extract data")
        self.extractButton.clicked.connect(self.extractData)

        self.tableButton = QPushButton("Show Data Table")
        self.tableButton.setDisabled(True)
        self.tableButton.clicked.connect(self.showTable)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.extractButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableButton)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.extractor.data.connect(self.saveData)

        self.tableWindow = None

    def extractData(self):
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)
        self.extractor.progress.connect(self.updateProgressBar)
        self.extractor.start()

        self.tableButton.setDisabled(False)

    def updateProgressBar(self, progressPercent):
        self.progressBar.setValue(progressPercent)

    def saveData(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def showTable(self):
        if self.tableWindow is None:
            self.tableWindow = RestaurantTable(self.data)

        self.tableWindow.show()
```

The data is extracted in  the extractData method of the MainView, but the window doesn't show

Comment: You're showing `RestaurantTable`, not its `tableWidget`. Either add a layout for `IconModes` and add the table widget to it, or just subclass it from QTableWidget and make any action done on `self.tableWidget` to `self`.